# File Upload progress on IE9

Tags: html, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I've read in a few places that file upload progress is not supported in IE9.

However I notice that gmail has some sort of solution for it. I've read articles from a couple of years ago that it is a flash-based solution but when I got the inspector tool out, I couldn't see any flash objects. I'm wondering whether anything has changed in that time.

Is anybody able to describe how gmail has solved the 'file upload progress' problem in IE9?

Comment: Very good question. I came looking for the answer. Not here yet.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how gmail does it, but one possible solution is to start the upload asynchronously (javascript, iframe, whatever) and then poll the upload progress regularly from the server.

Assuming you have some kind of session identifying the user, the upload is sent to the server which updates some progress variable in the user's session while the file is being transferred. At the same time, the client polls the progress variable once a second via separate AJAX calls to the server.